# Get possible sizes of product on product page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product

I am using the method `public function afterToHtml(ProductView $subject, $html)` on `use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View as ProductView;` to attach code on the product page for an item with multiple sizes/colours. I can see that this item has the "size" attribute, but in no way can I get a list of all possible sizes. If I use the typeInstance or normal product, all methods lead to empty arrays. Even though on the product page, multiple sizes are shown.

Is there a way to get the possible sizes using the product from `$subject->getProduct()` or should I even use a different overwrite or possibly a block to get this data?

There are some options suggested, which use `$product->getResource()`, but this seems to no longer work on more recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the below code to get all the sizes of a configurable product.

```
    $sizes = array();
    if($_product->isConfigurable()){
        $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
        foreach ($allProducts as $subproduct) {
            if ($subproduct->isSaleable()) {
                $sizes[] = $subproduct->getAttributeText('size');
            }
        }
        if(count($sizes)>0) {
        echo implode(", ", $sizes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this was Magento 2 code, but still this made me come up with the actual answer, which I put in a different answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jitendra Patel's answer, this is the actual code for Magento 2.

```
$sizes = array();
    if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        $allProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
        foreach ($allProducts as $subProduct) {
            if ($subProduct->isSaleable()) {
                $sizes[] = $subProduct->getAttributeText('size');
            }
        }
        if (count($sizes) > 0) {
            echo implode(", ", $sizes);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$id = YOUR_PRODUCT_ID;
$sku = 'YOUR_PRODUCT_SKU';
$_product = $block->getProductById($id);
$_product = $block->getProductBySku($sku);
echo $block->getImageOriginalWidth($_product, 'product_small_image') . '<br />'; 
echo $block->getImageOriginalHeight($_product, 'product_small_image') . '<br />';
```